# Adding subview inside cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Im trying to add views inside custom UITableViewCells. I tried using the [cell.contentView addSubview] method but the views dont appear. What is it I have to do. Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to create the subview i.e. is it being created correctly before you add it to the contentView?

Comment: The "[cell.contentView addSubview:subview];" should work, I think we need a little more information or code to help you with this one.

Comment: This is the code I have in the custom cell class:


UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 48);

[self.soundview addSubview: tmpView];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using custom cell then go to your custom cell class and ...

```
UIView *contentView;
contentView =[[UIView alloc]init];
```

then set frames of your view...
finally

```
[self.contentView addSubview:contentView];
```